# Is where command to get all graph's names in graph data base Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example, I've three graphs: Actors, Films and Roles.
I need get names of graphs, namely, Actors, Films and Roles.

Comment: Please provide more context. Do you have three node labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are trying to get back all [LABELS](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels) (and not "names of graphs") available in the database. You can do It running:

```
CALL db.labels();
```

Using the Movie Graph (`:play movie-graph`) the output will be:

```
╒════════════╕
│"label"     │
╞════════════╡
│"Movie"     │
├────────────┤
│"Person"    │
└────────────┘
```